# Using ChatGPT to write Mathematica code with the Ricci package

Tags: tensors, ai

I generally use ChatGPT to write mathematica code for me.

However, now I want to use a Mathematica package called Ricci. Whenever I try to ask ChatGPT to write me mathematica code using that package, it pretends to understand the instructions, but only gives me generic code that does not use the commands in the package.

How to best solve this problem? Will this never work in ChatGPT? I have uploaded the user manual for the Ricci package on ChatGPT as well. However, despite uploading the manual, it does not give me code specific to this package.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please click on the question mark icon on the [page banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkyXu.png) and take the site `Tour`. Subsequently, post an on-topic question along with a minimal example and properly formatted Mathematica code that you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: Learn to use Mathematica / Wolfram language - read the manual - write the code yourself. ChatGPT is unreliable for anything non-trivial. By using ChatGPT like this you're allowing your coding and thinking skills to atrophy, much like how calculators make people neglect improving their mental arithmetic. I'm not being glib... this is the only acceptable answer to this question.

Comment: my guess is that chaptGPT was not trained to use Ricci package. This is specialized package and it looks like chaptGPT did not encounter it when it was training its neural network reading the internet web pages? chatGPT does not actually think on its own. It has no brains. It can only use information it found on the internet and trained on.

Comment: @flinty- I understand your point, but disagree with it. Learning syntax has always been boring for me, and hence I have been unable to write mathematica or python code for most of my life. ChatGPT allows me to now incorporate programming (something I don't like) in my mathematical research, which is amazing for my research I think.

Comment: @Nasser- I understand that. I am only trying to find ways around this.

Comment: Then the only option is I see is to train chaptGPT  yourself on your data.  i.e. train it to use Ricci package. It is possible now do that. If you are using open AI chatgpt and it does know about things you want, that is one option. If you google "how to train my own chatgpt" you will find more information on this topic. obviously public chatgpt will know more about things that are more common, like Python, C, C++, javascript, java and so on than some little used package in less common language.

Comment: @matilda in which case, perhaps you should get an expert to write the code for you while you do the more visionary thinking. Since you're doing mathematical research, I wouldn't recommend publishing papers with code made by ChatGPT because it's dubious quality. Not only that, but it's hard to determine if that code has been plagiarized by it through overfitting. For anything else, it's fine to play around, although even then I've been very disappointed by the results.

Comment: If you post your question with complete description, links, etc. on [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com) you *might* get some practical advice from people developing things like [Chatbook](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/Wolfram/Chatbook)